# iOS - Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am uploading build to release app using Xcode 9.2 built with iOS 11 SDK. Binary is archived and uploaded successfully, but I get the following email back.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>   Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
>   CFBundleIconName is missing in the bundle ''. Apps that provide icons
>   in the asset catalog must also provide this Info.plist key. For more
>   information see
>   http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. Once these
>   issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected
>   binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I found a solution.

> [Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode9 iOS11 app release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release)

But i need little bit more. I don't want to use ***.xcassets** file for app icon. I want to use image in xCode project folder for app icon. 
Is it possible in xCode 9.2? if yes then how?

Comment: you can do that... that is the [legacy way](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW13) to define the icons in `info.plist` file.

Comment: but how can i do it. now when i upload build with this, apple send me mail i have referenced in question.

Comment: it is pretty much the same procedure like how you can add new keys to your `info.plist` file in general.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen this listed on any of the other posts but this was my issue.

Make sure to check the target membership of your assets directory! If you do not correctly link the membership here, you will get this same super-generic error(Apple should do something about the error messages).

[image]

The target membership should correlate directly to targets for which you are using the icons. For example, I use this single directory for both my main app, and watch app assets, you must specify this by selecting the appropriate member.

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct option not to use app icon from Assets

[image: Exact option]

Comment: already tried. but after using this i successfully archived and uploaded. but  received this email

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key CFBundleIconName is missing in the bundle ''. Apps that provide icons in the asset catalog must also provide this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.