# In Xcode, my info.plist file doesn't see even though the icons are in the assest folder. What is the solution?

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to make an icon to my application. I want to install an application but I'm getting errors like this. Can you help me. Although I have edited my info.flist file, I am getting many errors. That's why I couldn't send my app to the app store.

Prpblems[image]:
[image]
App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90713: `` Lack of Info.plist value. 'CFBundleIconName' is missing a value for Info.plist key 'com.arslantas.erc' in the package. IOS 11 or higher SDK-related apps implementation in a catalog it must provide symbols and provide a value for this Info.plist key. See http://help.apple.com/ for more information xcode / mac / current / # / dev10510b1f7. "

App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90022: "Required icon file missing. The package does not contain exactly '120x120' pixel app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch .png for iOS versions> = 10.0. Icon for iOS versions, location catalog Other May be required in the package. Make sure it contains the entries required for info.plist. See [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface%22App) Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90023: "Package icon is missing. .png format for iOS versions of iPad Pro, does not include an app icon exactly '167x167' pixels for iPad To support older operating systems, including icon maker.plist in the next package from a catalog See https://developer.apple Make sure that .com / documentation / bundleresources / information_property_list / user_interface contains appropriate entries for App St referencing the file. ore Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90023: "Required file missing .png for iOS> = 10.0 versions yet does not contain an exactly '152x152' pixel icon app for iPad. To support older operating systems, it is iconized in the package outside of a catalog. Make sure that the info.plist contains entries referencing the files. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface "App Store Connect Process Error ERROR ITMS-90704:" Missing Application Icon. PNG format 1024 An app icon of x1024 pixels must be added to the Asset Catalog of apps created for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, it cannot be submitted for review

Comment: Hi Kral Jesus, from what I see below you have tried a lot of what I tried as well, and you listed the same errors that I have now. Have you ever resolved this and how? I am looking for a solution and just can't figure out what's going on... The often-cited thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/46216718/1238150 did not help, also https://stackoverflow.com/q/70985583/1238150 did not.

Answer (score 2):

In info.plist add below entry

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

[image]

Make sure your Images.xcassets has AppIcon.

Here is Sample Images.xcassets : https://app.box.com/s/wv11yqi7dr6vb3nweq1d0evqyunp034c

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But this is already in the picture I sent. Frankly, I don't think I have any errors, but I am said to be xcode error.

Comment: @KRALJESUS did you select AppIcon in Xcode summary screen? https://app.box.com/s/jku0z29d7phahqai116adaiqd54i2j2f

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jcuJbhmnbWVo63H11Rwr8NZ53nB4Wmzx?usp=sharing here are my files

Comment: what would you suggest me to do?

Comment: @KRALJESUS simplest and 100% working solution is just drag my sample Images.xcassets to your project then goto finder and just change png images. Images.xcassets : https://app.box.com/s/wv11yqi7dr6vb3nweq1d0evqyunp034c

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. At the same time, I used photoshop and added my icon to your pictures and I tried it like that.it didn't work.I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that your app icon is configured correctly you should do next:

1. Check Assets.xcassets file is embeded to your target.
2. Verify that AppIcon is present in Assets.xcassets and has all needed icons:

[image]

3. Set AppIcon as a source in "App Icons and Launch Images"

[image]

Comment: thanks i did what you said but i still get an error