# Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing

Tags: ios, xcode

When submitting my app to the App Store I receive this email:

> TMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
> 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle '...'. Apps built with iOS
> 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must
> also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see
> http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.

I've tried everything in this post: [Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode9 iOS11 app release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release)

- I have an Asset from the beginning of the project (it was a Template).
- The bundle key is in the info.plist.
- The value of the key is the same that the name of the catalog.
- I have the asset selected in building settings.
- I have the Target Membership checked.

I'm using Xcode 13.1 and MacBook Air M1 2020

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: In Xcode 13 this is configured with a build setting, not by editing the Info.plist file directly.

Comment: I already have it on the Build Settings

Comment: I know only what you show in your question.

Comment: By build settings do you mean in the "App Icons and Launching Images" right? That corresponds to the third image on the question.

Comment: Check in Build Settings: `Project Name -> ` **`Mimoto`** `target -> select ` *`Build Settings`* `-> search for *Primary App Icon Set Name*`. Make sure for `Debug` and `Release` it is written `AppIcon`.

Comment: Yes, Debug and Release have "AppIcon" set. @Starsky

Comment: @matt I reconsidered your comment and instead of having the info.pliost edited and the build settings, I removed the info.plist key-vaklue and keep just the Build Setting. Now is working.

Comment: Check if Resources/Preview Content path is correct. details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76627233/6394265

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) mentioned in comments:

> In Xcode 13 this is configured with a build setting, not by editing the Info.plist file directly.

I had it set in both locations due to the instructions in this post: [Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode9 iOS11 app release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release)

I removed the *info.plist* key 'CFBundleIconName' and keep only the *Build Settings* and I could upload the archive with out any error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the answers like

- [Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode9 iOS11 app release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92638

But none of the got worked, So what I did was, I just upgraded the react-native version from 0.68.1 -> 0.68.2 and also created a new react-native app using the same project name and copied the ios folder blindly. This fixed my issue and later I applied the custom changes from the previous code.

During the copy, I found the following changes in ios/<project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. These changes made the fix for me

[image: ios/<project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj]

[image: ios/<project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj]