# Flutter submission to iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

[image: This the bottom part of the slots][image: My Asset.xcassets]I was able to upload to Apple store succesfully from xcode 12 but in less than 2 minutes, I always get email from apple with this error

> ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
> 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.logXXXhift.rccXXX'.
> Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset
> catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For
> more information see
> http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.

However, I've checked the Info.plist and the `<key>CFBundleIconName</key> <string>AppIcon</string>` is there.

The `Assets.xcassets` is also there, I've added the right format of icons with name as `AppIcon`.

It validates successfully and distribution also successful but apple will just send mail with the same error in few minutes after upload.

Is this because I'm uploading a flutter app or it's a common issue with iOS? Any form of assistance will be appreciated please.

Comment: I've always use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to generate app icon for both Android and iOS respectively, less work :)

Comment: @adadion, yes I used this too but apple still rejected the app and sent me that error. It worked fine with android.

Comment: Then maybe try one of the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release)

Comment: Try opening `Assets.xcassets` on xcode. Xcode itsself will show error if any. And ensure all slots are filled.

Comment: @adadion I've tried virtually everything mentioned in that link since last week. None worked

Comment: @LalKrishna, No error is showing from xcode. All AppIcon slots are filled but I noticed all the slots in LaunchImage are empty, can that be an issue? if yes, what sizes of images can I provide there.

Comment: Can you able to include screenshot of assets file? @Codedman

Comment: @LalKrishna, thank you friend, I've added screenshot of assets file

Comment: Is that all? I can't see slot called app icon

Comment: @LalKrishna, I've added the remain part of the slots

Comment: On identity inspector, Check box inside Target membership: `[x] Runner`. And try again.

Comment: @LalKrishna, thank you very much. After checking that box, some error popped up again about the image used in App Store slot but I've been able to resolve that and my app is currently under review now. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check target membership box under identity inspector. And try again.

Comment: Hello friend, Apple rejected my app after review with the reason that it crashes on lunch. I tried it from my Simulator and I realised its not coming up and throwing the following error  

```[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port```` Please any advise on this?

Comment: Sorry. I've no idea about that issue. Its purely on something in the file `profiler_metrics_ios.mm` on line 184.